# Pick a dependency by key/name when registering via RegisterType() or RegisterAssemblyTypes()?

Tags: autofac

In a scenario where I'm using Autofac with [TypedNamedAndKeyedServices](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices), Is there a way when using `RegisterType()` or `RegisterAssemblyTypes()` to register a type (which uses refection to find the appropriate constructor), to specify that one of its dependencies uses a keyed/named service? Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>();

...

public class ServiceA
{
    public ServiceA([ByName("online")] IDependencyB dependencyB, ...)
    { ... }
}
```

If not, then how about adding it to Autofac:

- How complicated would it be to implement? (I've only looked at the Autofac source very superficially.)
- Is specifying a dependency like this a good design? Is there a better way?
- Would that be a useful feature for anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as discoverable as I'd like, but:

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>()
   .WithParameter(
      (pi, c) => pi.Name == "dependencyB",
      (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDependencyB>("online"));
```

We've looked at simplifications in the past, butthe number of variations on this scenario is quite large. This approach covers all of them using mostly familiar APIs (System.Reflection and 'Resolve...()'.)